# Try/catch async function outside of async context

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-catch

I have a few classes which use 'dns' from node.js. But when an error occurs, my app is thrown. I made a siimple example with classes and throwable functions and I faced with the same problem. It's works if an exception is thrown from function but it doesn't work if an exception is thorwn from class.
Example:

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.t();
  }
  async t() {
    throw new Error("From class");
  }
}

async function test(){
  new Test();
}

try {
  test().catch(e => {
    console.log("From async catch");
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log("From try catch");
}
```

Output:

```bash
Uncaught (in promise) Error: From class
    at Test.t (<anonymous>:6:11)
    at new Test (<anonymous>:3:10)
    at test (<anonymous>:11:3)
    at <anonymous>:15:3
```

How to catch errors from try/catch block in this example?

UPD:
Full code (typescript):

```js
export class RedisService {
  client: any;
  expirationTime: any;

  constructor(args: RedisServiceOptions) {
    let redisData: any = {};
    if (args.password)
      redisData["defaults"] = { password: args.password };
    dns.resolveSrv(args.host, (err, addresses) => {
      if (err) {
        /// Handling error in main func
      }
      else {
        log.info("Using Redis cluster mode");
        redisData["rootNodes"] = addresses.map(address => {
          log.info(`Adding Redis cluster node: ${address.name}:${address.port}`);
          return Object({ url: `redis://${address.name}:${address.port}` })
        });
        this.client = createCluster(redisData);
      };
      this.client.on('error', (err: Error) => log.error(`Redis error: ${err.message}`));
      this.client.connect().then(() => { log.info("Connected to Redis") });
    });
    this.expirationTime = args.expirationTime;
  }
/// Class functions
}
```

Comment: If error is suppose to happen in class function t then it should be handled there

Comment: [Stop putting promises in constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572), and make your `test` function wait for the `t()` call when it makes it.

Comment: Can you share your actual code, please? Why are you calling `t` in the `new Test` constructor? What does `t` really do? Why does nothing need to wait for its results?

Comment: @Bergi Added constructor code. Looks a simple implementation. I thnik you will understand. So, I use error handler in main func and what I want - to share this handler with code classes. But when srv record is not found my application breaks.

Comment: How is the `RedisService` instance ever useful if the hostname fails to resolve or the cluster fails to connect? How do all the `RedisService` methods handle the absence of the `client`? Why are `client` and `expirationTime` typed as `any`?

Comment: RedisService is not the only service. Another function calls the class (Registter a service)/ Simply to say, `if (error in constructor) -> mainFunc -> log from handler in main func(Failed to register Redis service)`. Any - 'cos outside of dns.resolve fun the client member can be undefined and TS returns an error. About expiration time - `if (expiration is null) doesn't call expire function (Redis) `

Comment: But logging is not enough - the other function that created (tried to register) the `RedisService` needs to fail! How will it know about the error in the constructor?

Comment: "*outside of dns.resolve fun the client member can be undefined and TS returns an error*" - ignoring that error is a mistake. The `.client` member *can* and *will* be `undefined` until it's initialised, your code needs to handle that!

Comment: Thas was my question :)

Comment: But my question is solved. Thank you. I am begginner in async/await functions. I have understood using answers bellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it doesn't work if an exception is thrown from class.

In particular, when an asynchronous error event occurs in the `constructor`, yes. Like your question title says, you can't handle errors outside of an `async` context, and a constructor is not that.

Your current implementation has many issues, from `client` being `undefined` until it is initialised to not being able to notify your caller about errors.

All this can be solved by [not putting asynchronous initialisation code inside a `constructor`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572). Create the instance only once you have all the parts, use an `async` helper factory function to get (and wait for) the parts.

```
export class RedisService {
  client: RedisClient;
  expirationTime: number | null;

  constructor(client: RedisClient, expirationTime: number | null) {
    this.client = client;
    this.expirationTime = expirationTime;
  }

  static create(args: RedisServiceOptions) {
    const addresses = await dns.promises.resolveSrv(args.host);
    log.info("Using Redis cluster mode");
    const redisData = {
      defaults: args.password ? { password: args.password } : undefined,
      rootNodes: addresses.map(address => {
        log.info(`Adding Redis cluster node: ${address.name}:${address.port}`);
        return { url: `redis://${address.name}:${address.port}` };
      }),
    };
    const client = createCluster(redisData);
    client.on('error', (err: Error) => log.error(`Redis error: ${err.message}`));
    await this.client.connect();
    log.info("Connected to Redis");
    return new RedisService(client, args.expirationTime);
  }
  … // instance methods
}
```

Now in your main function, you can call `create`, use `await`, and handle errors from it:

```js
async function main(){
  try {
    const service = await RedisService.create(…);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("From async catch", e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You generate multiple async-requests but you can only catch errors from the first one:

1. You create a promise with `async function test()`.
2. Then you create a syncronous call within it, with `new Test()`, every error syncronously thrown from within it will be catched by the `catch`.
3. Then you generate another promise call from within the syncronous constructor, this error can't be caught by the `try/catch`-block or `.catch` at, or above the `async function test()`.

   It is similar to this:

   ```js
   constructor() {
     new Promise(() => throw new Error(''))
   }
   ```

So you have 3 possible ways to solve it:

1. You catch the error inside the `async t() {}`-call.
2. You catch it inside the constructor with `this.t().catch(console.error)` (which can't be forwarded to the try/catch block) as it is forwarded to the catch block of the Promise behind the async call. And if there is no `.catch` on the async call, you get the "Unhandled Promise rejection"-Error.
3. Don't call the async function from within the constructor at all, use it like this:

   ```js
   class Test {
     async t() {
       throw new Error("From class");
     }
   }

   async function test(){
     await (new Test()).t();
   }

   try {
     test().catch(e => {
     console.log("From async catch");
    });
   } catch (e) {
     console.log("From try catch");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make async methods)))

Your solution looks somewhat like this.

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.t();
  }
  t() {
    (async () => {
      try {
        throw new Error("From class");
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    })();
  }
}
```

Have a nice rest of your day

Comment: I thought I can catch all errors in "main" file. But because at least two people say to me make a handler in class so, okay.

Comment: @Aleksej No, you shouldn't handle them inside the constructor. You shouldn't call `this.t()` inside the constructor in the first place.